# my first EKS - error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Tags: kubectl, amazon-eks

I've seen this error in many previous questions, but as a complete beginner I'm not sure if those questions were relevant to my situation.

1. I've created a cluster called **wiz_try** using the AWS EKS gui.
   When it asked for a role, I've created a new one with EKS policy AmazonEKSClusterPolicy.
2. I've download AWS ICL and configured it. Also downloaded Kubectl.
3. checked that I see the cluster:

`aws eks --region eu-central-1 describe-cluster --name wiz_try --query cluster.status`

> ACTIVE

4. ran

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --name wiz_try --region eu-central-1`

this has created a config file:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: *******
    server: https://***.gr7.eu-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:399222411859:cluster/wiz_try
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:399222411859:cluster/wiz_try
    user: arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:399222411859:cluster/wiz_try
  name: arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:399222411859:cluster/wiz_try
current-context: arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:399222411859:cluster/wiz_try
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:399222411859:cluster/wiz_try
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - eu-central-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - wiz_try
      command: aws
```

5. 

`kubectl get svc`
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

I tried solving by running
`aws eks update-kubeconfig --name wiz_try --region eu-central-1 --role-arn arn:aws:iam::***:role/EKS_cluster_role`

as this is the role I created, but this is not helping.

what am I missing?

Thanks